# How to use Multiline comments in Visual Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to use the new feature of Multiline Comments in Visual Code released in [version 1.67](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67) (April 2022)?

[image: example of multiline comments]

Answer (score 0):

Press, ctrl+alt+A
with this combination you can